# Moving topnav to sidebar in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, layout-update

I'm extending the Magento Blank theme and I'd like to **move the catalogs main navigation to the sidebar** (it should be displayed vertically instead of horizontally)

I simply removed the original top navigation from the page with the following update in the Magento_Theme layout `default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

But I can't figure out how to add it to the sidebar via xml updates.

Answer (score 2):

To move blocks, you can use the `move` instruction as documented here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

In your case you should do the following:

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="sidebar.main" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It appears that there is no div for the sidebar in the output although the page is set to 2 columns with left sidebar and the main content moved on the right. The navigation now shows up again but on top of the content containers.

Comment: @DanielKemen what if you replace `sidebar.main` with `div.sidebar.main` ?

Comment: @DanielKemen also you should delete the code you pasted in your question to get the code I provided to work

Comment: I already tried both names because I found both on various examples. I also removed my example code. The new code now looks like this `<referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <move name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" destination="div.sidebar.main" />
        </referenceContainer>`

Comment: @DanielKemen don't use `<referenceContainer` (there is no need for it) and don't use `remove="true"` (useless in your case). Simply add the code I gave you inside the `<body>` tags of your layout file

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the "remove" attribute. I remove both - the attribute and the wrapper and my actual result is an error called: "Element name and destination must be specified". Code looks like this `<move name="catalog.topnav" destination="div.sidebar.main" />`

Comment: @DanielKemen please read my answer again. It should not be `name="catalog.topnav"` it should be `element="catalog.topnav"`